# Automapper ConstructUsing changing values

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have a CreateMap:

```
            CreateMap<ExtractInsertRequestViewModel, Extract>()
            .ConstructUsing(source => new Extract(source.MemberId,
                source.IsChargeBack,
                source.Type,
                source.Description,
                source.Value,
                source.VerifyBalanceBeforeRedeem))
```

Then I execute the transfomation (vm is my viewmodel):

```
var extract = Mapper.Map<Extract>(vm);
```

But inside my Extract ctor, I have 2 functions that may change the values (SetStatus and SetValue):

```
    public Extract(int memberId, bool isChargeBack, ExtractType type, string description, int value, bool verifyBalanceBeforeRedeem)
    {
        MemberId = memberId;
        IsChargeBack = isChargeBack;
        Type = type;
        Description = description;
        SetStatus(Status.A);
        IsAble = true;
        VerifyBalanceBeforeRedeem = verifyBalanceBeforeRedeem;
        SetValue(value);
    }

    public void SetValue(int newValue)
    {
        if (Type == ExtractType.DEBIT && newValue > 0 || Type == ExtractType.CREDIT && newValue < 0)
            newValue = newValue * -1;

        Value = newValue;
    }
```

The issue is, after the value was changed by any of this functions, the Extract object result is created with the original values.

For ex: I passed a Debit operation with a positive value. The SetValue method should convert to negative, but in the final object, the value still positive.

Seems to me that the ConstructUsing runs after the constructor. The constructor set the correct values but ConstructUsing overwrite the values with the original ones.

Any thoughts of what's going on here ??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use ConvertUsing instead.

Comment: Ok but can you explain why it happens ?

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu but if I use ConvertUsing, I need to write a Converter and the SetValue function should be moved from my domain to the custom converter, right ? It is a Business Rule, I don't want to move it from my domain...

Comment: No, you just replace ConstructUsing with ConvertUsing.

Comment: Lucian, thank you. It worked. Just one last question. How can I combine ConvertUsing and still use ForMember for fields that are not in ctor? Any simple example? tks

Comment: You cannot, that's the point. ConvertUsing takes over the mapping, ConstructUsing is just for construction. There is also [constructor mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html).